# stopping a list iterator from printing previous when previous.equals(" ")

Tags: java

how do I stop printing to screen when the condition is met? see code below:
Method continues to print previous to screen after adding the break;

```
while(listiter.hasPrevious()) {
        
        try {
            
             String country = listiter.previous();
             
             if(country.equalsIgnoreCase("Country Name")) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println(country); 
                }           
            
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            
            
            
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: ``String item = listiter.previous(); if (!item.equals("")) {... code ...; break; }``

Comment: If you want to stop the loop entirely, use `break`. If you just want to skip one iteration, you could put the print inside of a `if` block.

Comment: Post your [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
if(listiter.previous().equalsIgnoreCase("West Bank")) {

    break;
}
```

Comment: You should probably print the String "country". You're doing listiter.previous() twice in a cycle, so first initialize country, and then print it. That way listiter.previous() gets called just once in a cycle.